# Prevent Sidekiq from printing "(...) INFO: Sidekiq client with redis options {}" on tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, logging, sidekiq

I use Rails 4 default testing framework and have written some tests that also expect Sidekiq to do some work in the "background". But when I run `rake test` my test results look something like this:

```
.............2014-08-01T05:40:52Z 12000 TID-abcdef123 INFO: Sidekiq client with redis options {}
.....................................

Finished in 3.0s, 9.000 runs/s, 150.000 assertions/s.
30 runs, 400 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Now this looks fine with the tests but the log of the Sidekiq worker is really annoying. To prevent this log from happening I have tried this in my worker class:

```
class MyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: :my_queue

  def initialize
    Rails.logger.level = 2 # set to :warn level
    super
  end

  def perform(movie_id)
    # Rails.logger.level = 0 # set back to :debug level?

    # some code
  end
end
```

With both the `Rails.logger.level` line commented and uncommented, but the logged line didn't disappear. **How can I prevent Sidekiq from logging this when run with `rake test`?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add the following line to your sidekiq initializer (`config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`) to turn it off:

```
if Rails.env.test?
  Sidekiq.logger.level = Logger::WARN
end
```

Comment: Won't this affect the `Rails.logger.level` also? I still want to get messages from `Rails.logger` in `:debug` level.

Comment: No, it only affects the Sidekiq.logger

Comment: Could you please add a check if the environment ist `test` so the logger is only changed for the `test` environment? Something like `if Rails.env.test? ... end`. Then I'll accept your answer. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The official recommendation from

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging#turning-off-logging-in-the-test-environment

is to use

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Logging.logger = nil
```

This could go in your `spec/rails_helper.rb` if using rspec and rails.